# How to adjust nav bar height in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am getting data(autocomplete) on the search bar.

My problem is that when the suggestion show on the search bar, the height of the navigation increases.

Like This:

[image: Here is the problem]

I don't want that.

My real navigation bar look like:

[image: normal navigation bar]

Instead, I want the suggestions will show below the search bar but the navigation height do not get change. Navigation will not increase in height.

Here what I want to achieve:

[image: desired result navigation fixed while suggestions]

Here is my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>





<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light" style="padding-top: 0.15rem">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="newStoreName">Chaos Fast Food</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb" aria-expanded="true">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
  <div id="navb" class="navbar-collapse collapse hide">

    <ul class="navbar-nav">

      <div class="container-fluid">

        <form action="detail.php" method="post">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-group">
              <!-- type = "search" -->
              <input class="form-control border-secondary py-2 input-lg" type="text" name="search" id="vsearch" value="" placeholder="search for products" autocomplete="off">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

          // Here is the problem, when
          <li></li> suggestions shows below searchbar the navigation size increases. I want when suggestions will show the navigation height will be fix like 3rd image above(desired result navigation fixed while suggestions).
          <div id="fetcheditemlist">
            <ul>
              <li>Nike</li>
              <li>Nike</li>
              <li>Nike</li>
              <li>Nike</li>
              <li>Nike</li>

            </ul>
          </div>

        </form>

      </div>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="cart.php"><span class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>Cart</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I am getting the data successfully on search bar autocomplete suggestions. I am having only navigation problem.

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: I think you need to make `<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">` position absolute and it's parent's position relative, then adjust the top and value of ul class.

Comment: @Sarah, please share all source code by using jsfiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/) or codepen, whatever you feel familiar. I notice the `</nav>` doesn't match anywhere in your code.
If you share the full source code, I will completely make it worked

Comment: @KevinLee, I have update my code, now <nav> is there.

Comment: @am2505, I have update my code, now. Kindly suggest. Your code works navigation size did not increase but it gave all the suggestions on a horizontal line below the search bar. <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">